# started C with visual studio code, but facing problem

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

so i started with a ***C*** tutorial online on youtube.
i followed every steep but i dont know where i went wrong. i matched my steps many times but im unable to get the desired result.
i made a ***new file*** > ***named it first.c*** > **typed the code** > ***new terminal*** > ***entered gcc f(tab)***
im suppose to get an ***exe file*** according to the tutorial but it doesn't happen :(

[here is the screenshort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUkd2.png)

im unable to keep up with the tutorial, every info and help appreciated.
thank you ***:D***

***p.s. extremely sorry if i was unable to present my question properly since its my firt time here, im struggling a bit.***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't other programs see the changes I made to a file in VS Code until I save those changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76984829/why-dont-other-programs-see-the-changes-i-made-to-a-file-in-vs-code-until-i-sav)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't normally develop in Windows so this is a wild guess worth trying.
1- Save your file "Ctrl + s"
2- Do "gcc ./first.c" rather than "gcc .\first.c"

Comment: i just did that. there appeared a exe file for just a second and then disappeared again. and the same error appeared again :(

thnx for the help tho :)

Comment: LOL I KNOW what is happening. You have not saved your file! :D Look at the dot next to the file name on the top. That means it has not being saved. Press Ctrl + s or file-> save

Comment: OMG......it really worked....i cant thnk enough sir :") thak you so much :D

Comment: Always a pleasure and don't lose hope. Programming (specially in C) can be very challenging and you might want to destroy your PC sometimes, but in the long run it all starts to make sense. You can do it!

Comment: they shouldn't need to change the directory separator. they're using powershell.