# Is there any problem with my files and folder?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flask, terminal, errno

I just have installed flask in VSCode following a freecodecamp tutorial (everything went well) but when i tried to run the basic appweb at flask, the terminal shows an error that i don't fully understand:

```
(env) (base) erickpruneda@MacBook-Air-de-Erick flask introduction % python3 haha.py
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '/Users/erickpruneda/Documents/Documentos - MacBook Air de Erick/Documentos/developer/flask introduction/haha.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I honestly don't know what to do.

Comment: the error is telling you that the file `/Users/erickpruneda/Documents/Documentos - MacBook Air de Erick/Documentos/developer/flask introduction/haha.py` doesnt exist. Check that the path is correct

Comment: but how is saying it doesn exist if i just created it and executed it???

Comment: does that file exist? is it a [new unsaved file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76984829/11107541)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the file `haha.py` exists in the directory `/Users/erickpruneda/Documents/Documentos - MacBook Air de Erick/Documentos/developer/flask introduction/.` You can check this by navigating to the directory in your terminal and running `ls` to list the files in the directory.
2. Make sure that you are running the `python3 haha.py` command from the correct directory. If you are not in the correct directory, you can navigate to it by using `cd` command.