# Undefined Reference to `main' While Using WSL/Ubuntu at VSCode (.text+0x1b)

Tags: c, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cs50

I had read and tried the solutions for the problem but to no avail. So, here is my code block inside my file called `hello2.c`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cs50.h"

int main(void)
{
    string name = get_string("What is your name: ");
    printf("hello, %s\n, name");
}
```

The file is stored in a folder called `helloFile`

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/frqIX.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QU7JB.png)

Here is my Clang Version

```
Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

As I'm trying to enter a command

> clang -o hello2 hello2.c -lcs50

An error has occurred

```
root@DESKTOP-BNGGIH0:/mnt/c/Users/Jason tee/OneDrive
/文档/C-Folder/helloFile# clang -o hello2 hello2.c -lcs50
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `main'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So, how to solve this problem such that the command will run properly?

Comment: In the console, if you run the command `cat hello2.c`, does it show the code you expect? Did you forget to save the file in your editor?

Comment: I wonder what is `cat` in Linux? I'm new to programming btw. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: That is not programming related. Just general Linux command. This command just displays file content to terminal. For any command, just try `man cat` in terminal. You can also just search in Google `man <cmd>`.

Comment: related to problems due to not saving: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76984829/11107541). Also, please add the output of `clang --version` to your question post.

Comment: There is probably no main function in hello2.c and you typed this question by hand instead of opening the file with an editor and copying the contents. For example: you mistyped `get_string` and you mistyped the printf parameters.

Comment: In the tiny blurry screenshot we can see `hello2.c` is 0 KB, so it's probably empty.

Comment: @nurettin The mistyped `printf()` parameters and the supposed wrong `get_sting()` (what is that function, never saw any function with a similar name in standard C, nor Posix nor glibc, same with `get_string()`?) is not a indication that he didn't try to compile that. Since it is absolutely possible to try to compile nonsense. The problem is probably not that the code he posted would not be the same as in the editor (it probably is), the problem more likely is that the content in the file is not the same as in the editor (because of not saving it).

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 `get_sting()` is a function from the dreadful CS50 library which comes with the even more dreadful CS50 course.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 just try harder.