# VSCode and changing branches

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

In VS Code I can change branch by clicking bottom left of the screen and selecting the branch I want:

[image]

[image]
There is some indication that the new branch is loading, but then the code on the screen never actually updates to reflect whats in that branch. Am I missing something?

If I click on files changed (bottom right) I can see what I expect to see in that branch.

[image]

I just want to experiment with that branch, but despite swapping can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, you seem to have unsaved changes in the editor tab for the file of interest. If the file really has differences in the branch you've switched to, but the filesystem change caused by the branch switch will not be reflected in your editor until you do something to trigger VS Code to make you pick what to do about the conflict between your unsaved changes and the "filesystem copy" of the file. See also [Why don't other programs see the changes I made to a file in VS Code until I save those changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76984829/11107541). TL;DR either close your editor tab, upon which VS Code will ask whether you want to save your changes, or try to save, in which case VS Code should ask whether you want to overwrite the disk copy, in which case your changes will then be recognized/treated by Git as unstaged changes.