# Changes Tab In Source Control Not Showing After New Branch Was Created In VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, github, version-control, branch

Disclaimer: I haven't done any coding since 2019 and am starting again, so I'm rusty.

After creating a new branch and adding code to the new branch, the changes tab does not appear, only Publish Branch remains. I am on the new branch as the name of the new branch is shown in the bottom left-hand corner, and the gutter is showing the code changes.

What should be showing up in the left column is the tab "changes" and the files with the "open file" "discard changes" and "stage changes" icons below but does not show up. Only "Publish Branch" shows.

Git is working with GitHub, I published a test branch already to make sure that wasn't the issue.

***I added in new code to the new branch, and was expecting changes tab with the files under to show up on the left hand column of vs code in source control. It did not.

Comment: show output of git status

Comment: I figured it out. Once I manually saved the file from vs code everything in the source control column worked. The video tutorial from the vs code youtube showed it working automatically

Answer (score 0):

I'm tempted to close this as a duplicate of [Why don't other programs see the changes I made to a file in VS Code until I save those changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76984829/11107541), but I feel that more explanation is needed to close the loop (I.e. Why doesn't VS Code's SCM View display the (unsaved) changes that you made in VS Code?). What you should do is first read that Q&A as pre-readings. TL;DR other programs will generally only see "changes to files" if they are *written* to the filesystem- not if they are just unsaved changes in VS Code. The extra explanation needed here is that VS Code's SCM functionality is built on top of SCM providers, and the Git SCM provider for VS Code is mostly built on Git itself, which will *not* see unsaved changes to files. As for why the video you were watching had those changes show up in the SCM view automatically, the person recording the video might have had auto-save on. The Q&A I linked above has info about how to enable/configure auto-save.